# How to only change part of a form element parent list

Tags: forms, 8

I'm making a form element with `'#tree' => TRUE`. I have no idea where this element will be used and so I have no idea what it's list of parents will look like. I leave `'#parents'` undefined:

```
$elements['foo'] = array(
  '#tree' => TRUE,
  // Some more keys
);
```

If I don't define `'#parents'` on this item it will be added automatically because of the `'#tree' => TRUE`, and become something like this:

```
'#parents' => array('some', 'unknown', 'parents', 'foo')
```

I then add an element further down in the tree structure:

```
$elements['foo']['bar']['baz'] = array(
  // Keys here
);
```

If I don't define `'#parents'` on this subelement, it will be:

```
'#parents' => array('some', 'unknown', 'parents', 'foo', 'bar', 'baz')
```

But what if I want it to be this:

```
'#parents' => array('some', 'unknown', 'parents', 'foo', 'baz')
```

I can't set

```
$elements['foo']['bar']['baz']['#parents'] = array('foo', 'baz');
```

because then it will lose the unknown parents. So how do I do this?

Comment: What is the use case for such granular control over the #parents?